# Raspberry Pi - hosting website - change index.html - where to put other .html files and folders?

Tags: pi-4, filesystem, nginx

I have installed Nginx on a Rasperry Pi 4 to host a website.

I can see the default nginx index.html on my IP Address 192.0.9.11 (example IP)

I just have a few questions:

- What can I use to edit the index.html page - in windows I have used notepad++, is there an inbuilt editor in Raspberry Pi?
- How do I 'replace' the default index.html page - when I 'open with...' (right click on index.html file) and make a change I am advised that I cannot save any changes; and
- Where do I / can I put my other files / folders associated with the index.html page - i.e. about.html, features.html, pricing.html etc and the .css / .images folder to make the whole website function.

Any comments/feedback very welcome.

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: Please note, these are common questions that can easily be researched. This site is mostly for issues with stuff that you tried researching, but couldn't find anything. See [this help topic for more info](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: A major reason new Pi users don't find such information is that they search "raspberry pi text editor" instead of "linux text editor".  WRT a GUI there are lots of such things available; WRT console the choice is more limited; `nano` (built-in) is very basic. `vim` (available in various forms) is much more feature rich but also much more difficult for new users.

Comment: I think the default GUI built-in editor on RpiOS is probably `mousepad`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mousepad_(software)  You should be able to find this in the Applications menu.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the command `nano [file name]` in the terminal to edit your file.
2. You probably don't have access to the directory it is in. In the terminal, you can cd to the directory the index.html file is in (Or open the terminal in the directory in the file manager by going to Tools > Open current folder in terminal) and run `sudo nano index.html`. Sudo is running the command as root which is the admin.
3. Check where the index.html is in. If it is the same file on the website, there is your directory.